# Using Picamera for motion detection

Tags: raspberry-pi2, motion-detection

I am using Pi camera and motion detection software to detect motion. I have installed motion by " sudo apt-get install motion" and have edited the configuration file "/etc/motion/motion.conf" to start in daemon mode. But i am unable to understand the output. Whenever motion is started using " sudo service motion start" camera LED glow up and give the image on display for few seconds. This keeps on repeating after 10-12 seconds untill motion is stopped.  :( 
Also if I try streaming video in web browser, its shows error as website unavailable.  :(

i am using raspberry pi 2 model B with debian- jessie. Is there any problem with debian-jessie as all the installation guides i have gone through are for debian-whezzy.

Please help!!  :)

Comment: This question is more suited for [unix.se], [raspberrypi.se] or [su].

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this](http://elinux.org/RPi-Cam-Web-Interface), proven solution with numerous other functionalities.

Edit the files in /var/html to configure the UI and functions